# Should there be a tag for Python library [requests]?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently asked a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/213026/finding-unimplemented-tasks-on-rosetta-code-using-requests) where I was interested in if I used the Requests library correctly. To my surprise, when I was adding tags, I didn't see the one for this library. Googling `"import requests" site:codereview.stackexchange.com` gives more than 700 results for me, so it should be a pretty popular technology.

Should we add this tag or no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not surprise me that there's no [requests](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/requests) because most questions are not about the `requests` itself, but just use `requests` as part of some larger process. In the same way, it would not make sense to add [integer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer) just because a program uses an integer.

Having said that, as I read through your question, it really is not about replicating `requests` as much as it is about using `requests` to accomplish a larger task.

In my opinion, the tags are pretty good on your question, and adding `requests` would not add value.

Nice question, by the way!

Comment: I agree with what you said. But it's unclear for me, why then we have tags for any other libraries, such as [beautifulsoup], [numpy], [opencv], etc.

Comment: Not all library tags are equal, I admit. There is a threshold at some point where a  library becomes so influential on the language itself that unless you are familiar with the library, the code is essentially unreadable. For example, [tag:numpy] and [tag:opencv] are clearly massively influential on how the program itself is structured. Things in the JavaScript world like [tag:react] or [tag:jsquery] are similar. Even in Java, where sub-components of the core librarues are used, like [tag:lambda], it changes the nature of the program itself. In my opinion, `requests` does not cross that line.